# Lift and Shift of Cloud based applications

Tags: migration, cloud

We have a web applications developed with Angular and .Net, which is deployed on an Azure Cloud platform, lets say  External A-Cloud.

We need to lift the same application and host in a different Internal Cloud Platform, lets say Internal B-Cloud.

How can we achieve this, please share some thoughts to do the ground work to start the process,

Warm Regards
KdM

Migrate an externally hosted cloud based application  to our Cloud platform.
We have both AWS and Azure, but the externally hosted one is in Azure cloud platform

Answer (score 0):

We can move from any Cloud to any Cloud. But we need to understand few points first.

1. How are the Angular and .Net hosted in Azure
2. If they are hosted on simple Virtual Machines - Then we can create a Virtual Machine in AWS and Migrate or host the apps in AWS ( Yes we definitely need to consider foundation of AWS like VNETs , hope thats already done )
3. If the Angular and .Net hosted in Azure is of Kubernetes and docker based
4. We need to Create EKS in AWS and then as its docker based, the same Manifest files etc would work in EKS as well with minor changes

We can look at migration tools as well if they are Windows VM based